# Using G++ to compile multiple *.cpp and *.h files in Sublime 2

Tags: c++, g++, sublimetext2, build-system

On a MAC I can successfully compile a c++ program from the command line using

```
  g++ *.cpp *.h -o executablename
```

However it fails from within Sublime 2 - I created a build system for this using

```
 {
 "cmd" : ["g++", "*.cpp", "*.h", "-o", "executablename"]
 }
```

With these results

```
 i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2: *.cpp: No such file or directory
 i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2: *.h: No such file or directory
 i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2: no input files
 [Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]
```

However, if I create the build system with specific filenames in the project it works:

```
{
"cmd" : ["g++", "Test.cpp", "TestCode.cpp", "TestCode.h", "TestCode2.cpp", "TestCode2.h", "-o", "executablename"]
}
```

How can I create a build system in Sublime 2 that uses command line patterns to compile multiple files like I can on the command line?

Comment: You never directly compile `.h` files. They are compiled as needed, when they are `#include`d in `.cpp` files. So at least remove the `*.h`.

Comment: The reason why using `*.cpp` in Sublime Text fails is, *gcc* does not do wild card expansion. When you run *gcc* from command line with wild cards, the shell expands them and gives *gcc* a list of file names. So you need to find out how to do equivalent (of getting file names by wildcards or other similar method) in Sublime Text.

Comment: Also note, directly calling the compiler is very, how should I put this, *primitive* way to build software. Usually makefiles or some other more advanced method are used.

Comment: Getting a c++ to build and run from Sublime 2 has been a challenge just to get it to work at all. If anyone has suggestions for a better way I would appreciate that.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks hyde.

After playing with the build system based on your suggestion, this works:

```
{
"cmd" : ["g++ *.cpp -o executablename"],
"shell":true
}
```

Comment: Use `"cmd": ["g++ *.cpp -o test && gnome-terminal -- './test'"]` (or equivalent terminal program like konsole or xterm instead of gnome-terminal) to then run it. I was using `gnome-terminal -x sh -c './test'`, but then it said to just use `--` to terminate the options and put the command afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You should perhaps use something like this:

```
{
 "cmd" : ["gmake"]
}
```

Or possibly just `make` instead of `gmake`. But if you have `gcc`, GNU make should be in same directory. Below example *Makefile* is tested with GNU Make, it might not work without small modifications elsewhere.

So here's a very primitive Makefile for you. Important! It should be named `Makefile` so GNU Make will find it without arguments, and in it you **must** use actual tab char for indentation (before *g++* and *rm* command below).

```
CXXFLAGS := -Wall -Wextra $(CXXFLAGS) # example of setting compilation flags

# first rule is default rule, commonly called 'all'
# if there many executables, you could list them all
all: executablename

# we take advantage of predefined "magic" rule to create .o files from .cpp

# a rule for linking .o files to executable, using g++ to get C++ libs right 
executablename: TestCode.o TestCode2.o Test.o
    g++ $^ -o $@

# $^ means all dependencies (the .o files in above rule)
# $@ means the target (executablename in above rule)

# rule to delete generated files, - at start means error is ignored
clean:
    -rm executablename *.o
```

But even using hand-written Makefile can be considered primitive these days. You should perhaps install and learn to use [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/).