# Cannot compile multiple C++ files using wildcard (*) on Mac, works fine on Windows

Tags: c++, macos, sublimetext2

I'm trying to compile multiple C++ files at once using g++ in a Sublime Text 2 [sublime-build file](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/build). Using a wildcard works fine on my Windows Desktop, but doesn't work on my Macbook, how would I get the wildcard to work on my Mac?

**sublime-build file:**

```
{
"cmd": ["g++", "-std=c++11", "-I", "/Users/Dan2/YorickTheSavant/include",

"/Users/Dan2/YorickTheSavant/src/*",

"-o", "/Users/Dan2/YorickTheSavant/Yorick the Savant",
"-F", "/Users/Dan2/Library/Frameworks",
"-framework", "sfml-system",
"-framework", "sfml-window",
"-framework", "sfml-graphics"],

"file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
"working_dir": "/Users/Dan2/YorickTheSavant/",
"selector": "source.c, source.c++",

"variants":
[
    {
        "name": "Run",
        "cmd": ["/Users/Dan2/YorickTheSavant/Yorick the Savant"]
    }
]
}
```

**Output:**

`clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/Dan2/YorickTheSavant/src/*'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is this:

> [Using G++ to compile multiple *.cpp and *.h files in Sublime 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21956428/using-g-to-compile-multiple-cpp-and-h-files-in-sublime-2)
>
> The reason why using *.cpp in Sublime Text fails is, gcc does not do
>   wild card expansion. When you run gcc from command line with wild
>   cards, the shell expands them and gives gcc a list of file names. So
>   you need to find out how to do equivalent (of getting file names by
>   wildcards or other similar method) in Sublime Text.

The OP was able to use this workaround:

```
{
"cmd" : ["g++ *.cpp -o executablename"],
"shell":true
}
```

Comment: I tried adding `"shell":true"` but now I'm getting this error: `clang: error: no input files`

Comment: Again, the problem is that 1) Sublime is passing your "cmd" to the Mac OS shell such that it's one string literal ... instead of a set of shell commands, and 2) the shell is never getting a chance to expand the wildcard "*.cpp".  SUGGESTION: `"cmd" : ["g++", "*.cpp", "-o",  "executablename"]`