# How to compile multiple files in sublime text 3

Tags: c++, sublimetext3, build-system

I'm using Sublime Text 3 to write some school projects and I have to write a program with some custom headers which have 1 function. The problem is that the build system (what sublime text writes in cmd to build) only puts the main.cpp file and not the headers and .cpp of the headers in the cmd, so it's not compiling properly.

I'm looking for a way to compile with headers just by writing the main.cpp file in the cmd ("g++ main.cpp -o main.exe") or to modify the build system so it adds all the headers in the cmd line ("g++ headersourcefile.cpp header.h main.cpp -o main.exe") (this one compiles ok)

The build system is written in JSON (which I have no idea about :))

---Edit---

My problem is that Sublime Text is only compiling the file that I'm writing on, and not the #includes that I made, f.e. #include "organiser.h". The build system that I'm using is a custom one that I wrote based on some of them found on the Internet (that's why I thought I've done something wrong). Now I'm trying the "make" build system and I have no idea how it works(it says: "no target specified and no makefile found. Stop.).

Thanks for you attention :)

Comment: JSON is just a way to format data, you can remove this part from your question completely. Also, fix the typo "heathers" where you mean "headers".

Comment: What about using specifically designed tools like `make`?

Comment: I don't know nothing about "make", could you be more specific please?

Comment: The build system that ships with Sublime for compiling C/C++ only compiles (or compiles and then executes) the current file. It's a bit unclear what your question is based on how you ask it, but you don't need to include header files on the command line, you `#include` them in your code. That said, you do need to tweak the build or use another build system like `make` if you need to compile multiple source files. Can you clarify a bit in your question if that's what you want to do?

Comment: I've seen someone who says that you need to write -I [dir] source.cpp in the cmd part of the build system. Haven't figured out how to do that tho.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Andrew! You can make his build run with the code:

```
{
    "cmd" : ["g++ *.cpp  -o $file_base_name &./$file_base_name"],
    "working_dir": "$file_path",
    "shell":true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As sugested I got myself into makefiles and got one of them working, it's building the project and doing what I wanted. Needed to reinstall the `mingw` tho, to get one with `msys2` so `make` could work correctly.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

This is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21956602/1599699

```
{
  "cmd" : ["g++ *.cpp -o executablename"],
  "shell":true
}
```

or, as I mentioned in the comments:

"Use `"cmd": ["g++ *.cpp -o test && gnome-terminal -- './test'"]` (or equivalent terminal program like konsole or xterm instead of gnome-terminal) to then run it. I was using gnome-terminal -x sh -c './test', but then it said to just use -- to terminate the options and put the command afterwards."